# Can't find the derivation ${\rho^2\sin\phi}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

I have accepted that the equation of a sphere in spherical coordinates is ${\rho^2\sin\phi}$. The triple integral is just to nice. What I don't understand is what happened to ${\theta}$. How can you evaluate the integral through ${d\rho d\phi d\theta}$ if the polar (xy) plane is not in the derivative?

Author's note: After much conversation on the topic I realize the above was a gross misinterpretation. But it did start me on the path to the right answer.

Comment: equation of sphere is $\rho^2 = c$ !

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw: Not following you there. What is c? And are you saying C factorial?

Comment: sorry for that it $c$ (constant) . I am saying that you have written the wrong equation here . In spherical co-ordinates $\rho^2 = C $ is the equation of a sphere .

Comment: What you probably mean is that the volume element of a sphere is given by $\rho^2 \sin \phi$, assuming $\phi$ is the angle measured with the $z$ axis. Have you learned about the Jacobian?

Comment: No but that's my next foray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the volume element $dV$ in various coordinate systems. We know that in the cartesian system it takes the form $dV = dx \, dy \, dz$. How does this change over a different system? Answer: using the Jacobian. In the case of spherical coordinates, you make the following substitutions:

$$\begin{cases}
x = r \cos \theta \sin \varphi, \\
y = r \sin \theta \sin \varphi, \\
z = r \cos \varphi,
\end{cases}$$

where I am assuming that $\theta$ is the angle in the $xy$ plane and $\varphi$ is the angle with the $z$ axis (also known as azimuthal angle, I believe).

The Jacobian is then the determinant of the matrix composed by the partial derivatives of $x,y,z$ with respect to $r, \theta, \varphi$. We write it as

$$J = \frac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (r, \theta, \varphi)} = \begin{vmatrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \varphi} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \varphi} \\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial z}{\partial \varphi} \end{vmatrix}.$$

By performing the calculations you'll find $J = - r^2 \sin \varphi.$ Since we are interesting in the unsigned volume, the volume element becomes

$$dV = dx \, dy \, dz = \left\vert \frac{\partial (x,y,z)}{\partial (r,\theta,\varphi)} \right\vert \, dr \, d \theta \, d \varphi = r^2 \sin \varphi \, dr \, d \theta \, d \varphi,$$

that is, we take the absolute value of the Jacobian. The sign in it means that this coordinate switch reversed the orientation, but we are not interested in that.

Comment: As a note, the Jacobian here is just a fancy way of computing the scalar triple product.  Each column is a spherical basis vector expressed in terms of the Cartesian basis vectors.  That is, the first column is $e_r = \partial_r x e_x + \partial_r y e_y + \ldots$, and so on.  The scalar triple product $e_r \cdot (e_\theta \times e_\phi)$ is what's being computed, and hence, the connection between this quantity and volume should be clearer.

Comment: @Muphrid The jacobian can easily be seen to be the proportional volume of the parallelopiped that approximates the image of a small cube under the inverse map. That is, if a small cube in the $(r,\theta,\phi)$ space has volume $V$ then its inverse image has volume approximately $|J|V$. This easily generalizes to higher dimensions, while that does not seem to be the case for the triple product.

Comment: Indeed, the analogues to scalar triple products involve a little more formalism, along the lines of exterior algebra and such. The relationship between determinants and volumes--that determinants tell us how volumes change in size and orientation under linear maps--is key here.  Of course, one should ask, "What linear map?"  And that, in turn, demands some picture of the transformation. One that can be useful is to imagine a spherical coordinate system on flat space and to deform that grid into a Cartesian one.

Comment: Sort of. The Jacobian is a linearization of your map. In straight lines you get the slope: essentially whatever lengths you originally have will be changed by the factor $m$. In the general sense, the Jacobian is telling you this: for small boxes in cartesian coordinates, the corresponding boxes in spherical coordinates will have that volume magnified by the factor $\rho^2 \sin \phi$. This can be greater, smaller, etc.

Comment: A lot to digest. I understand now what the Jacobian is but its use eludes me. Still a shot in the dark I noticed in proving the formula for a cone that in the triple integral, the first integral seems to describe the 1 D displacement of points on a curve, the 2nd integral seems to describe the 2 d displacement of a line, and the third seems to describe the 3d displacement of a surface. Just my interpretation cont... –

Comment: So then would I be right in saying the Jacobian will describe any point on the sphere? Just trying to picture how such an elegant proof is derived from ∫∫∫ρ 2 sinϕdρdθdϕ  especially since I got it wrong the first time.

Comment: Sorry about the order had to edit but was out of time

Comment: So reading through the explanation of the Jacobian it is a ratio of the partial derivatives AND the determinant of the |${\delta}$|?

Comment: So what I am doing when I multiply the partial derivatives by the Jacobian is scaling the old coordinate system to match the new? Or am I way off base here?

Comment: You are not multiplying partial derivatives by the Jacobian. Do you mean $J \, d \rho \, d \theta \, d \phi$? But yes, you are scaling the volume from your old coordinate system to the new one. The new is always a "multiple" of the old, at small amounts.